# Error with TI f28m36 in code composer studio

Tags: signal-processing, texas-instruments, code-composer

In CCS when i want to program in flash memory it stops and says that can't write in sector N.
Can everybody help me?
What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, could you please provide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I use ti's examples, not my own projects.